# How to prove "(∀x. P) ∧ Q ⟹ ∀x. P" using conjunct1 in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to prove this:

```
lemma
  assumes 0: "(∀x. P) ∧ Q"
  shows "∀x. P"
proof -
  show ?thesis using 0 by (rule conjunct1)
qed
```

I'm getting:

```
Failed to apply initial proof method⌂:
using this:
  (∀x. P) ∧ Q
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ∀x. P
```

What should I change in my proof?

Comment: Are you sure you want `∀x. P`? Here, `P` does not refer to `x`? Or did you simplify it just for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference got in your way. If you fix the type of `x` in both cases, i.e.

```
lemma
  assumes 0: "(∀(x::nat). P) ∧ Q"
  shows "∀(x::nat). P"
proof -
  show ?thesis using 0 by (rule conjunct1)
qed
```

it works.

Without this type annotation, Isabelle infers the first `x` to be of type `'a`, i.e. a type variable, and the second `x` gets a different type variable.

Comment: Also, I very much think you meant `(∀x. P x) ∧ Q`.

Comment: No. If you use `(∀x. P x) ∧ Q` the OP’s problem does not appear, as the `P` fixes the type of the two bound `x` to the same variable.